# Python Data Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a python solution to convert an input file and read it as it is into a program written in PYTHON3.

My input file consists of the following data:

```
    { "h" : ["a","c","e"],
      "d" : ["d", "a","g"],
      "e" : ["f", "a", "b", "c"],
      "b" : ["d","c"],
      "c" : ["g", "c","a"],
      "g" : ["w","x","y"]
    }
```

I have tried the following

a) `datafile = open("infile.txt","r").read()`
   Error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers

b) `datafile = open("infile.txt","r").readline()`
   Error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers

c) `datafile = open("infile.txt","r").readlines()`
   Error message: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

By the way, I am new to Python.

Comment: Try reading it as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: None of these lines will throw *that* error…

Comment: Something else must be going on. Are you trying `eval()` the string read from file?

Answer (score 0):

one solution will be:

```
import ast
datafile = open("infile.txt","r").read()
values = ast.literal_eval(''.join(datafile.splitlines()))
values['h']
```

as suggested by Evgeny, you can use json module as well:

```
import json
json_data=open('myfile.txt').read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data['h'])
```

Comment: Come on, it is just a `json`, no need for eval()

Comment: @Evgeny, Yes agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the concpet of dictionary by now in python.The below code will help you. Assume the name of your file to be file1.txt Now as mentioned by someone in comments you should use json library

```
with open("file1.txt") as fp:
    read=json.load(fp)
```

Now printing read will give you dictionary of your data

```
print(read)
```

will print your dictionary

> {'g': ['w', 'x', 'y'], 'c': ['g', 'c', 'a'], 'e': ['f', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'd': ['d', 'a', 'g'], 'h': ['a', 'c', 'e'], 'b': ['d', 'c']}

Note :- Dont forget to import json.

> import json

**Important** This is rather simple question. Kindly refrain from asking such questions and gaining downvotes for them

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses. I have been sick for a few days and not able to respond back to any of the suggestions. 

I tested the JSON suggestion and it works perfectly.  My solution is as follows:

import json
with open('python_dataconversion.txt', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        data = json.loads(data_file.read())

Comment: My input file is called  “python_dataconversion.txt” and it contains the following data:

{ "h" : ["a","c","e"],
      "d" : ["d", "a","g"],
      "e" : ["f", "a", "b", "c"],
      "b" : ["d","c"],
      "c" : ["g", "c","a"],
      "g" : ["w","x","y"]
    }

My program generated two output files:

Outputfile_1_nodes:

["h", "d", "e", "b", "c", "g"]

Outputfile_2_edges:

[{"a", "h"}, {"c", "h"}, {"e", "h"}, {"d"}, {"d", "a"}, {"d", "g"}, {"e", "f"}, {"e", "a"}, {"e", "b"}, {"c", "e"}, {"d", "b"}, {"c", "b"}, {"g", "c"}, {"c"}, {"c", "a"}, {"g", "w"}, {"g", "x"}, {"g", "y"}]

Comment: PROBLEMS:

Now that I have created two output files, I then wrote another program to read these output files as input files and I got the following errors:

Error Message:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

My read statement from the “Outputfile_2_edges” is as follows:

with open('Outputfile_2_edges.txt', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

Could someone tells me how to fix this please?